# How to create event tickets for apple wallet ( for large numbers )

Tags: ios, xcode, rest, ticket-system, apple-wallet

I am new for creating Apple wallet pass. We are organising for an event, to enter the event customer need to show their event tickets. Event ticket consists of *seat number*, *row number* , *gate no* and some of the essential things. I created an event ticket successfully and it working fine with apple wallet. I go through "https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/YourFirst.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH2-SW1" this above link to create event ticket.

Now the question is, i want to change the seat number, row number , date ,etc for each and every ticket. So any possible way to do that easily ? We are planning to handle the changes through REST api and i don't want to pay for websites to do these stuff. I found that there are possible way to manage by some of websites. I really don't want to do that.

Step by step guide, or links that are briefly explain this thing will be helpful.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You will need some web service to both create the PKPass on demand and also to verify the pass when it is scanned. Your QR code should include a digital signature to prevent forgery and this will require you to use a secret key on your server